# Variable not carrying over to function

Tags: forms, powershell

I've made a MDT tool for work that creates a computer and it needs to add the MDT LocationRoles to the computer.

I'm using a Combobox, where you can select the role and I'm using the `SelectedIndexChanged` to get the SelectedItem:

```
$comBox_LocationRole_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $locationRole = $comBox_LocationRole.SelectedItem
    Write-Host $locationRole
}
```

I can see in the console, that it works fine and it writes out the location role.

I then have a function that creates the MDT computer object in the MDT database - which works just fine.
However, I'm not able to use my `$locationRole` in the function - it's just empty.

The part of the function where I use the `$locationRole` is here:

```
if(!($mdtComputer -match $args[0]))
    {
        $pinCode = Get-Random -Maximum 999999 -Minimum 100000
        New-MDTComputer -assetTag $args[0] -description $args[0] -settings @{ OSInstall = 'YES'; SkipWizard = 'NO'; ServerA = $PinCode; OSDComputerName = $args[0]; ComputerName = $args[0] } |  Out-Null
        Get-MDTComputer -assetTag $args[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerA
        
        if($mdtComputerID -ne $null -and $locationRole -ne $null)
        {
            Clear-MDTComputerRole -Id $mdtComputerID
            Set-MDTComputerRole -id $mdtComputerID -roles OS-Windows_10_Enterprise_X64,AP-Normal,$lbl_LocationRole.Text
        }
        Write-Host "Role : $locationRole"
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT - someone wanted the full script**

**Script with functions:**

```
    $locationRole = ""
$comBox_LocationRole_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $script:locationRole = $comBox_LocationRole.SelectedItem
    Write-Host $locationRole
}

$btn_DeleteMDTComputer_Click = {
    Delete-MDTComputer
}

$btn_CreateMDTPinCode_Click = {
    Create-MDTComputer
}

. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'MDT_Pincode.designer.ps1')

#region method
function Create-MDTComputer
{
    $lbl_Output.Text = ""
    $computerName = $txtBox_ComputerName.Text
    $user = $userAccount
    $passwordFile = "\\$server\SWCTools\SWCScripts\MDT\PasswordNew.txt"
    $keyFile = "\\$server\SWCTools\SWCScripts\MDT\AES.key"
    $key = Get-Content $keyFile
    $myCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $passwordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

    $remoteSession = Invoke-Command -ComputerName dklyscms1 -Credential $myCredential -ArgumentList $computerName -ScriptBlock {
        
        Import-Module -Name "C:\MDT\MDT\MDTDB.psm1"
        Connect-MDTDatabase -sqlServer $server -database MDT | Out-Null

        $mdtComputer = Get-MDTComputer -assetTag $args[0] | Select-Object AssetTag
        

        
        Write-Host $locationRole

        Write-Host $role

        if(!($mdtComputer -match $args[0]))
        {
            $pinCode = Get-Random -Maximum 999999 -Minimum 100000
            New-MDTComputer -assetTag $args[0] -description $args[0] -settings @{ OSInstall = 'YES'; SkipWizard = 'NO'; ServerA = $PinCode; OSDComputerName = $args[0]; ComputerName = $args[0] } |  Out-Null
            Get-MDTComputer -assetTag $args[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerA
            
            $mdtComputerID = (Get-MDTComputer -assetTag $args[0]).ID
            Write-Host "ID :"
            Write-Host $mdtComputerID.ID
            if($mdtComputerID -ne $null -and $locationRole -ne $null)
            {
                Clear-MDTComputerRole -Id $mdtComputerID
                Set-MDTComputerRole -id $mdtComputerID -roles OS-Windows_10_Enterprise_X64,AP-Normal,$lbl_LocationRole.Text
            }
            $RoleText = $comBox_LocationRole.SelectedItem
            Write-Host $RoleText
            Write-Host "lbltext : $script:locationRole"
        }
    }
    if($remoteSession)
    {
        $lbl_Output.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Verdana',[System.Single]46,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
        $lbl_Output.Text = $remoteSession
    }
    else
    {
        $lbl_Output.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Verdana',[System.Single]15.75,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
        $lbl_Output.Text = "Computer already exists"
    }
}
```

**Design:**

```
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
$MDT_Pincode = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$label1 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$lbl_Output = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox]$pictureBox1 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]$txtBox_ComputerName = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$btn_CreateMDTPinCode = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$btn_DeleteMDTComputer = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]$comBox_LocationRole = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$lbl_LocationRole = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$button1 = $null
function InitializeComponent
{
$resources = . (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'MDT_Pincode.resources.ps1')
$label1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label)
$txtBox_ComputerName = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button)
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button)
$lbl_Output = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label)
$pictureBox1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox)
$comBox_LocationRole = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
$lbl_LocationRole = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label)
([System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize]$pictureBox1).BeginInit()
$MDT_Pincode.SuspendLayout()
#
#label1
#
$label1.AutoSize = $true
$label1.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Verdana',[System.Single]8.25,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
$label1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]26,[System.Int32]79))
$label1.Name = [System.String]'label1'
$label1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]81,[System.Int32]13))
$label1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]0
$label1.Text = [System.String]'PC number:'
#
#txtBox_ComputerName
#
$txtBox_ComputerName.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$txtBox_ComputerName.CharacterCasing = [System.Windows.Forms.CharacterCasing]::Upper
$txtBox_ComputerName.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]26,[System.Int32]99))
$txtBox_ComputerName.Name = [System.String]'txtBox_ComputerName'
$txtBox_ComputerName.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]99,[System.Int32]21))
$txtBox_ComputerName.TabIndex = [System.Int32]1
#
#btn_CreateMDTPinCode
#
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]314,[System.Int32]99))
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.Name = [System.String]'btn_CreateMDTPinCode'
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.TabIndex = [System.Int32]2
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.Text = [System.String]'Create'
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$btn_CreateMDTPinCode.add_Click($btn_CreateMDTPinCode_Click)
#
#btn_DeleteMDTComputer
#
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]233,[System.Int32]99))
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.Name = [System.String]'btn_DeleteMDTComputer'
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.TabIndex = [System.Int32]3
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.Text = [System.String]'Delete'
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$btn_DeleteMDTComputer.add_Click($btn_DeleteMDTComputer_Click)
#
#lbl_Output
#
$lbl_Output.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Verdana',[System.Single]15.75,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
$lbl_Output.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(([System.Int32]([System.Byte][System.Byte]240)),([System.Int32]([System.Byte][System.Byte]78)),([System.Int32]([System.Byte][System.Byte]35)))

$lbl_Output.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]12,[System.Int32]151))
$lbl_Output.Name = [System.String]'lbl_Output'
$lbl_Output.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]388,[System.Int32]61))
$lbl_Output.TabIndex = [System.Int32]5
$lbl_Output.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
#
#pictureBox1
#
$pictureBox1.Image = ([System.Drawing.Image]$resources.'pictureBox1.Image')
$pictureBox1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]-5,[System.Int32]-5))
$pictureBox1.Name = [System.String]'pictureBox1'
$pictureBox1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]418,[System.Int32]53))
$pictureBox1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]6
$pictureBox1.TabStop = $false
#
#comBox_LocationRole
#
$comBox_LocationRole.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Popup
$comBox_LocationRole.FormattingEnabled = $true
$comBox_LocationRole.Items.AddRange([System.Object[]]@([System.String]'LT-Norway',[System.String]'LT-Denmark',[System.String]'LT-Sweden',[System.String]'LT-LITHUANIA',[System.String]'LT-Belgium',[System.String]'LT-UK_Flint_Niell',[System.String]'LT-US_OCC',[System.String]'LT-US_Ben_C_Gerwick',[System.String]'LT-CA_Buckland_Taylor',[System.String]'LT-US_JENNY',[System.String]'LT-Oman',[System.String]'LT-Qatar',[System.String]'LT-INDIA',[System.String]'LT-Korea',[System.String]'LT-UK',[System.String]'LT-Poland',[System.String]'LT-Uganda',[System.String]'LT-Singapore',[System.String]'LT-Denmark_Arkitema',[System.String]'LT-Norway_Arkitema',[System.String]'LT-Sweden_Arkitema',[System.String]'LT-Canada',[System.String]'LT-United_States'))
$comBox_LocationRole.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]132,[System.Int32]99))
$comBox_LocationRole.Name = [System.String]'comBox_LocationRole'
$comBox_LocationRole.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]95,[System.Int32]21))
$comBox_LocationRole.TabIndex = [System.Int32]7
$comBox_LocationRole.add_SelectedIndexChanged($comBox_LocationRole_SelectedIndexChanged)
#
#lbl_LocationRole
#
$lbl_LocationRole.AutoSize = $true
$lbl_LocationRole.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Verdana',[System.Single]8.25,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
$lbl_LocationRole.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]129,[System.Int32]79))
$lbl_LocationRole.Name = [System.String]'lbl_LocationRole'
$lbl_LocationRole.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]39,[System.Int32]13))
$lbl_LocationRole.TabIndex = [System.Int32]8
$lbl_LocationRole.Text = [System.String]'Role:'
#
#MDT_Pincode
#
$MDT_Pincode.ClientSize = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]412,[System.Int32]236))
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($lbl_LocationRole)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($comBox_LocationRole)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($pictureBox1)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($lbl_Output)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($btn_DeleteMDTComputer)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($btn_CreateMDTPinCode)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($txtBox_ComputerName)
$MDT_Pincode.Controls.Add($label1)
$MDT_Pincode.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Verdana',[System.Single]8.25,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
$MDT_Pincode.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$MDT_Pincode.Icon = ([System.Drawing.Icon]$resources.'$this.Icon')
$MDT_Pincode.MaximizeBox = $false
$MDT_Pincode.Name = [System.String]'MDT_Pincode'
$MDT_Pincode.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$MDT_Pincode.Text = [System.String]'MDT Pincode Manager'
$MDT_Pincode.add_Load($MDT_Pincode_Load)
([System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize]$pictureBox1).EndInit()
$MDT_Pincode.ResumeLayout($false)
$MDT_Pincode.PerformLayout()
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name base -Value $base -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name label1 -Value $label1 -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name lbl_Output -Value $lbl_Output -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name pictureBox1 -Value $pictureBox1 -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name txtBox_ComputerName -Value $txtBox_ComputerName -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name btn_CreateMDTPinCode -Value $btn_CreateMDTPinCode -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name btn_DeleteMDTComputer -Value $btn_DeleteMDTComputer -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name comBox_LocationRole -Value $comBox_LocationRole -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name lbl_LocationRole -Value $lbl_LocationRole -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MDT_Pincode -Name button1 -Value $button1 -MemberType NoteProperty
}
. InitializeComponent
```

Comment: Looks like a [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2) issue.

Comment: I did try adding $Global:locationRole = $comBox_LocationRole.SelectedItem, but that doesn't change the outcome, unfortunately

Comment: Just making sure, you also updated all other instances of $locationRole to $Global:locationRole as well?

Comment: Yes I did - still not getting anything

Comment: Use `$script:locationRole = $comBox_LocationRole.SelectedItem` and use that scoping everywhere in your code where that variaable is used inside a function or scriptblock

Comment: Didn't change the outcome unfortunately

Comment: [1] In the Script with functions, you should define the functions **before** calling on them, so move these up. [2] In function `Create-MDTComputer` you do not use scoping on variable `$locationRole`, so this will be an undefined (i.e $null) local variable there [3] We do not see function `Delete-MDTComputer`, but probably no scoping going on there as well..

Comment: Answer to [1] - The order of the events, is something that is created automatically by PowerShell Pro Tools in Visual Studios. The thing is, the two click events, works fine regardless of the order, so would that really be the issue? Answer to [2] I did add the scoping ($Global:locationRole) in the entire scope - it's just not shown in the edit, as I wanted to show, how it was before I changed it around. Would it be possible for you to make an answer, showing code, as I am not sure if I've understood what you've said entirely.

Comment: Okay, so I've pointed it down to it losing the variable, when it goes into the $remoteSession. So I guess I need to somehow pass it into the $remoteSession somehow?

Comment: Oops yep, you need to add "$using:" preceding the variable name in your scriptblock. From the page boxdog linked "using: - Used to access variables defined in another scope while running scripts via cmdlets like Start-Job and Invoke-Command." I don't think you need the "$script:" tags at all